# Is it possible to produce two random graphs that always pass each other

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, correlation, random-walk

My question is whether it is possible to create two graphs that go up one point or fall one point at a time [e.g. every minute] in a random walk, and they will pass over each other for sure all the way, I have attached a picture to explain,

[image: Correlation with constant deviations]

Comment: I don't quite understand. What do you mean by "fixed deviations between them", and what does this have to do with your question body, your graph and the highlighted points in your time series? Please clarify.

Comment: If the question is primarily concerned with how to get the desired graph printed, this appears to be a programming question (how do I amend the code) rather than a statistical question.

Comment: The question is statistical and to explain with an example I have added the graph

Comment: The search term to use is "Brownian bridge."